# Security Onion 2.3 The IP being routed by Linux is not the IP address assigned to the management interface?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, code

I have just installed Security Onion 2.3 and I faced some issue with network configuration, first of all I have 2 interface

1- Host Only for Management

2- Nat with internet connection

but I receive this error

```
The IP being routed by Linux is not the IP address assigned to the
 management interface?
```

What's wrong in my configuration and how canI fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issues.  I ended up reducing the number of interfaces to one.

Also, I switched from VMWare3 NIC type to E1000 NIC type.

One of these changes helped me.

Answer (score 0):

> Try removing the IP address from your sniffing interface.

https://github.com/Security-Onion-Solutions/securityonion/discussions/2441